# How to permamently disable SYN-Cookies?

Tags: linux, centos, selinux

We run a site with big traffic surges and, because of that, SELinux usually thinks that the traffic is a SYN flood attack. We have this same problem on many different CentOS servers.

Despite `/etc/selinux/config` being set with disabled or permissive, when the servers boot, selinux is in enforcing mode again.

The only way to disable SELinux is by doing `echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies` every time the servers boot.

I know that one solution could be to do a cron job with the abovementioned command on every boot but I wonder if anyone has some idea of what could be the reason why the modification of `/etc/selinux/config` is not enough (maybe it is enabled somewhere else; any idea on where to look or how to find it?).

Answer (score 5):

In `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` you want to have `SELINUX=disabled` and reboot.

Source: http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/sec-sel-enable-disable.html

Comment: You are right, there is also `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` but both `/etc/selinux/config`  and `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` are set as `SELINUX=disabled` and despite of that `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies` still says `1` after reboot.

Comment: Just found the solution. No need to disable selinux, just to edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` where it says `net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1` to `net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 0`

Comment: @Zilo could you post that as an answer please for posterity?

Answer (score 2):

While I would rather keep SELinux **on** and make a policy to allow whatever is breaking your server you can always try this to disable SELinux.

```
$: sudo echo 0 > /selinux/enforce
```

Comment: This command failed for me - I needed to run it completely in a subshell so 'root' was actually "writing the file", _viz_:
> 
>     $ sudo echo 0 > /selinux/enforce
>     -bash: /selinux/enforce: Permission denied
>     $ sudo bash -c 'echo 0 > /selinux/enforce'
>     $

Comment: This worked better:  
  
    `$ sudo bash -c 'echo 0 > /selinux/enforce'`

Answer (score 0):

The Syn-Flood protection mechanism that is enabled by default (cf. `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies`) has nothing to do with SELinux.

IOW, the syn-flood protection is enabled whether or not SELinux is enabled.

See also the [kernel documentation on `tcp_syncookies`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt):

> tcp_syncookies - BOOLEAN
>       Only valid when the kernel was compiled with CONFIG_SYN_COOKIES
>       Send out syncookies when the syn backlog queue of a socket
>       overflows. This is to prevent against the common 'SYN flood attack'
>       **Default: 1**
>
> Note, that syncookies is fallback facility.
>       It MUST NOT be used to help highly loaded servers to stand
>       against legal connection rate. If you see SYN flood warnings
>       in your logs, but investigation shows that they occur
>       because of overload with legal connections, **you should tune
>       another parameters** until this warning disappear.
>       See: tcp_max_syn_backlog, tcp_synack_retries, tcp_abort_on_overflow.
>
> syncookies seriously violate TCP protocol, do not allow
>       to use TCP extensions, can result in serious degradation
>       of some services (f.e. SMTP relaying), visible not by you,
>       but your clients and relays, contacting you. While you see
>       SYN flood warnings in logs **not being really flooded**, your server
>       **is seriously misconfigured**.

(emphasis mine)

You can permanently change such settings by dropping a file in `/etc/sysctl.d`, e.g.:

```
# echo 'net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=0' > /etc/sysctl.d/23-network
```

Those files are applied during the next reboot or `sysctl --system` call.