# SELinux disabled, net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies and nfs

Tags: nfs, selinux, autofs

OS is RHEL 6.2.

I appear to be having an issue with SELinux. I've disabled it in `/etc/sysconfig/selinux`, however, when my host starts the command `sestatus` show that I'm in permissive mode.

Searches in Stack Exchange bring me to this U&L Q&A: [How to permamently disable SELinux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30342/how-to-permamently-disable-selinux). That question mentions a scenario that sounds similar to mine.

Which prompted me to have the following questions:

1. what does `net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1` (=0) means?
2. Is it safe to turn to this to 0?

**NOTE:** My original problem is related to automount/nfs.

Sometimes when a distant Filesystem is neither mounted nor unmounted, we have to restart `autofs`. I don't know if this is happening under heavy traffic or if this issue is related to the `net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies` problem above or not.

So I'm trying to get a better understanding of `net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies` so that I can ascertain whether this is related to my `autofs` problem or nott.

Comment: What does the SELinux bit have to do with your 2 questions? As it stands your Q is a bit confusing. If you can clean it up we can reopen it.

Comment: @slm Searches in Stack Exchange bring me this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30342/how-to-permamently-disable-selinux, on this page disabling selinux is related to `net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies`, I was just asking for precision. Sorry to have been unclear.

Comment: OK, I think I see what you're asking now. I've edited the Q further and reopened. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1

Helps in preventing SYN flood attack on the system. A value of 0 will disable it.From security point of view, it is ideal to keep it on i.e. set value to 1. However, its pretty safe to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [kernel documentation for `tcp_syncookies`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt):

> **tcp_syncookies** - BOOLEAN
>       Only valid when the kernel was compiled with CONFIG_SYN_COOKIES
>       Send out syncookies when the syn backlog queue of a socket
>       overflows. This is to prevent against the common 'SYN flood attack'
>       **Default: 1**
>
> Note, that syncookies is fallback facility.
>       It MUST NOT be used to help highly loaded servers to stand
>       against legal connection rate. If you see SYN flood warnings
>       in your logs, but investigation shows that they occur
>       because of overload with legal connections, **you should tune
>       another parameters** until this warning disappear.
>       See: tcp_max_syn_backlog, tcp_synack_retries, tcp_abort_on_overflow.
>
> syncookies seriously violate TCP protocol, do not allow
>       to use TCP extensions, can result in serious degradation
>       of some services (f.e. SMTP relaying), visible not by you,
>       but your clients and relays, contacting you. While you see
>       SYN flood warnings in logs **not being really flooded**, your server
>       **is seriously misconfigured**.

(emphasis mine)

So this has nothing to do with SELinux and it's very likely not related to your NFS/autofs issues.